# Absolute positioned image goes out from a relative div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

In my site header, I have 2 divs (`pontok_bal` and `pontok_jobb`), that have background images given in css.

If I put these 2 divs in the header-main container div, the result is the same : I cant see the `pontok_jobb` div.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.pontok_bal{ 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; left:10px; 
  background:url(../images/assets/pontok_bal.png); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
 }
.pontok_jobb{ 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; right:10px; 
  background:url(../images/assets/pontok_jobb.png); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
 }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="pontok_bal"></div>
  <div class="pontok_jobb"></div>
  <div class="header-main container">
    <div class="logo col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <a href="https://corvinstyle.com" title="Corvinstyle"><img id="logo" src="https://corvinstyle.com/images/assets/uj-logo-2.png" alt="Corvinstyle" style="margin-top:30px;"></a> </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 fejlec_div"> <a href="https://corvinstyle.com" title="Corvinstyle"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://corvinstyle.com/images/assets/uj-termekek-2.png" alt="Corvinstyle"></a> </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The `.header` div has `position:relative`, and the width is 100%.

My problem is that when I view the site on mobile, or in chrome, I zoom in on it and I never see the `.pontok_jobb` div because it goes out or I dont know what it does.

You can check the site on this link: [Click here](https://corvinstyle.com)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about your background image CSS style.
You should have your image fit your div width and height.

Try using this `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Okay, but if i give this to it, i cant position the .pontok_jovbb div to bottom 0, it is always as top 0.

Comment: I don't understand your situation. The `background-size: contain` is not related to the `.potok_jovbb` position!

Answer (score 0):

your "pontok_jobb" background image width is 1920px and its on right side. please cut the image by removing blank space and give background position to right css.